# Citrix XenApp - Logoff via CMD/DLL/Something

Tags: javascript, windows, session, citrix, xenapp

I need your support.

Following case: I created a script for performance measure (AutoIT) which opens the Internet Explorer, loads a Citrix XenApp Page, logs in and starts an application from there.

My Problem is the Logout/Disconnect/Closing of the Session.

### Using the URL behind the Logoff Button

In the upper right corner is a Logoff and a disconnect Button. These both calls a Javascript function which rewrites the URL

Logoff (Logoff in the Web GUI and logoff in the Citrix Session. Closes all open Windows from Citrix)
`javascript:location.replace('../site/logout.aspx?CTX_Token=F692CFB5C3282DDEFE1084DAB381EAF4')`

disconnect (Logoff in the GUI, closes the session. In the next login it reopens all citrix windows)
`javascript:location.replace('../site/disconnect.aspx?CTX_Token=F692CFB5C3282DDEFE1084DAB381EAF4')`

The CTX_Token is not static. After every logon I have a new token.

My goal is: To close, if there is one, the open session, before I open a new session.

Call the URL without token, with token set to 0 and to complete F/0,

- ../site/logout.aspx
- logout.aspx?CTX_Token=0
- logout.aspx?CTX_Token=00000000000000000000000000000000
- logout.aspx?CTX_Token=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Every time I get only a State Error

> State Error
>
> There is a problem with your session. For security reasons, you must close your browser window and log on again to continue accessing your resources.
>
> To log on again, you must restart your browser.

No success on this way :/

### A Parameter in the Citrix Connection Center

My next hope was a Parameter in the Receiver.exe to disconnect the session.

In the GUI of the concentr.exe is a disconnect and logoff button.
But the exe has no help in the cmd.
It seems, that this exe has parameters (Task Manager `concentr.exe /startup`
I tried it with following parameters. Every time only the GUI starts...

- ?
- help
- logoff
- quit
- kill
- exit
- stop
- shutdown
- settings

Maybe one of you have an idea...

### Quit the Citrix Connection Center and the Citrix Receiver

These both ways are like disconnect in the Webgui.

Not that what I wanted..

### Close the IE (logoff in the Browser) and kill the open Citrix Windows

Not really the correct way. It is possible, that there is process which survives everything

### Other ways?

I searched for DLL Calls, for APIs, CMD and other stuff. I found nothing.

Maybe here is a Citrix Pro which is reading this and can deliver me an answer.

Have a nice day

Nice regards

Hagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are automating/webscraping StoreFront but it's better to use the [StoreFront SDK](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/storefront-web-interface/sdks/storefront-services-api-30.html). Here is an example for Logoff taken from the documentation:

**Example: LogOff Request**

```
POST http://www.example.com/Store/sessions/v1/logoff HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: application/vnd.citrix.sessionresults+xml
Content-Type: application/vnd.citrix.sessionparams+xml
Content-Length: xxx
Authorization: CitrixAuth ...

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sessionparams xmlns="http://citrix.com/delivery-services/1-0/sessionparams">
<clientName>xxxxxxxxx</clientName>
<deviceId>xxxxxxxxx</deviceId>
<tickets>
<ticket>85EB92973D2C3804F93A99AAEC232D</ticket>
<ticket>85EB92973D2C3804F93A99AAEC232A</ticket>
</tickets>
</sessionparams>
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.citrix.sessionresults+xml
Content-Length: xxx
Cache-Control: no-cache

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sessionResults xmlns="http://citrix.com/delivery-services/1-0/sessionresult" status="success" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found no easy way to send it successfully to the server.


Regarding the link: I have no Account to enter the documentation of the SDK.


I create a function in AutoIt which uses the GUI of the Citrix Receiver to close/logout the session.